# How to get shipping class name not slug woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

```
global $product;
$shippingClass = $product->get_shipping_class();
```

this returns the slug but I need the name how do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After `$shippingClass` add below lines it will get the name.

```
      $shipp_classname= get_term_by('slug',$shippingClass ,'product_shipping_class');
      echo $shipp_classname->name;
```

So complete code is following.

```
      global $product;
      $shippingClass = $product->get_shipping_class();

      $shipp_classname= get_term_by('slug',$shippingClass ,'product_shipping_class');
      echo $shipp_classname->name;
```